# If combobox1 includes an item in combobox2 list, then return error

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, duplicates, userform

I have a Userform that has 2 Comboboxes on it.

-- One acts as a drop down with team names ie: Team 1, Team 2, Team 3, -- The other combobox is used as a text input.

I would like a VBA code that, after pressing an action button, it checks the input box value, and cross references it with the list inside the first combobox.

-- If the value of the box is NOT in there, I want it to action a index match function that will change the list value on some page and reload the userform. -- if the value of the box IS there, I want it to prompt the user with a message box "Cannot change team, duplicate or something".

I tried variables, For each statements & list index. No luck so far.

Ive changed the code that much that I do not have any semi working examples, but I will add this (I know its broken) but I will try convey what I want to happen:

KEY: Combobox1 = Select_Team (drop-down) Combobox2 = Change_Team (input)

```
For Each item In Select_Team

If Select_Team.listindex = Change_Team.Value Then
MsgBox "Duplicate"

Else:
MsgBox "This was changed"

'(This code works, I just need to implement the IF function)
Evaluate("=INDEX('Teams'!B2:S21,2,MATCH(""" & Select_Team.Value & """,'Teams'!B3:S3,0))") = Me.Change_Team.Value

Unload Me
Edit_Teams.Show
```

I got it working but I could not get it to flag duplicates. I ended up having a combobox with:

```
Team 1
Team 1
Team 1
Team 4
Team 5
Team 6
Team 7
```

The teams are pulled from another page from cell values, So the items are "hardcoded" and therefore cannot be removed by listindex -1.

I want the index match function to change the team names (which it does) but only if the Change_Team value is not in the dropdown combobox.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your mistake is at how you interpret `ComboBox.ListIndex`. This property returns an integer, not the value of the corresponding item. In fact in your code, it should be sufficient to use `item` as it is.

```
For Each item In Select_Team.List
    If item  = Change_Team.Value Then
        MsgBox "Duplicate"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next item
MsgBox "This was changed"
Evaluate("=INDEX('Teams'!B2:S21,2,MATCH(""" & Select_Team.Value & """,'Teams'!B3:S3,0))") = Me.Change_Team.Value
Unload Me
Edit_Teams.Show
```

This modified version of your code should work if you have declared the variables correctly. Also, I do not know the entirety of your setup, but be careful with using ComboBox.Value versus ComboBox.Text.

Hope this works, good luck!

Comment: Hi Lorne. 
I get what you mean, getting integers and strings mixed up. 

When I use your code as is, it says "Object doesn't support this property or method"

So I put a "Dim Item As Object" in front of the code and now its not working. 

I don't mess with declared variables much, what am I missing :0

Comment: In fact you do not even need to declare "item" as a variable at all. The only problem with the above code is a mistake on my behalf, it should be "in Select_Team.List" instead of just "in Select_Team". Select_Team is a ComboBox object, ComboBox.List on the other hand is a Variant through which we can iterate. I have edited my answer accordingly, I hope it works now. Sorry for my lack of attention the first time. (Also consider using another name than "item". It may be reserved.)